# Objectivec: Custom fonts are not working properly on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uifont

In my app i have used custom fonts for

Helvetica-Condensed-Light-Light (Helvetica-Condensed-Light-Light.ttf)

Helvetica-Conth  (Helvetica-Conth.ttf)

these are working fine in iOS 6 but in iOS font appears as like we want but the text wraps un expectedly differently On multiple line and as well as in single line labels.

Following steps i foolowe to have custom font

1. Added font family .ttf files in to xcode project,
2. Added fonts in info.plst
3. make sure these are exist in Build phases - copy bundle resources
4. set the font to the label as following code

   greetingLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Condensed-Light-Light" size:15];

[image]

[image: iOS 7]

No matter about Text allignment

No matter about TextWraping

No matter about Font size

No matter about Number of lines

In all scenarios it behaves differently

```
 UILabel *greetingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - 2*x, ht)];
    [greetingLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [greetingLabel setText:@"We believe that people like you can create a social movement and enable innovative solutions to challenges across the globe"];
    [greetingLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Condensed-Light-Light" size:13]];
    [greetingLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [greetingLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
    [greetingLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    [self.view addSubview:greetingLabel];
```

Comment: How do you create UILabel? Is Autolayout in place?

Comment: yes i have creeated using programitically, the heit is increased by me

Comment: I guess that `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Condensed-Light-Light" size:15];` isn't nil. Could you show the code you use?

Comment: Yes added in edit code

Comment: Only with these 2 fonts? You don't use `NSAttributedString` (thinking about `NSParagraphStyle` issue or `NSKernAttributeName` issue)?

Comment: please share the `.ttf` files too.